# Access 'cat' output as an array in 'bash'

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to access some numeric values that a regular 'cat' outputs in an array.

If I do: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies`

I get:  `51000 102000 204000 312000 ...`

So I scripted as below to get all elements in an array and I tried to get the number of elements.

```
vAvailableFrequencies=$(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies)
nAvailableFrequencies=${#vAvailableFrequencies[@]}
```

The problem is that `nAvailableFrequencies` **is equal to the number of characters in the array, not the number of elements**.

The idea is to be able to access each element as:

```
for (( i=0;i<$nAvailableFrequencies;i++)); do
   element=${vAvailableFrequencies[$i]
done
```

Is this possible in bash without doing something like a sequential read and inserting elements in the array one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array like this:

```
arr=($(</sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies))

nAvailableFrequencies=${#arrr}
```

- `$(<file)` reads and outputs a file content while `(...)` creates an array.

Answer (score 1):

You just need another set of brackets around the `vAvailableFrequencies` assignment:

```
vAvailableFrequencies=($(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies))
nAvailableFrequencies=${#vAvailableFrequencies[@]}
```

Now you can access within your for loop, or individually with `${vAvailableFrequencies[i]}` where `i` is the number of an element

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` 4 or later, use

```
readfile -t vAvailableFrequencies < /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

(or, if you need to use `sudo`,

```
readfile -t vAvailableFrequencies < <(sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies)
```

)